Can we setup third Party SSL certificate AWS lightsail loadbalancer
can we setup the thirdparty SSL certificate on AWS lightsail load balancer
I don't see any option of import or attache custom certificate.
Any help would greatly appreciated

based on my research , we cannot setup the custom SSL certificate on lightsail load balancer.
Date: 2-May-2024
